# Hbase .META table

Tags: hbase

I have a doubt regarding the location of Hbase -ROOT- table and .META table .I have read that the Hbase -ROOT- table resides in the znode of the zookeeper , So when the client query the -ROOT- the information of the server hosting the .META is found . My doubt is does the .META reside in one single server. If so if that server crashes the information of  .META table is lost. Or am I wrong ? Could any one help.

This is my reference: https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/11/16/tip-2-hbase-meta-layout/

Comment: current release, hbase 2.x, only a single primary meta region, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3171
for details. after support region replica, meta region can have replica region as @Ruba mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in [The Apache HBase Reference Guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.catalog.meta) The -ROOT- table is removed since HBase 0.96.0 and the location of .META table is currently stored in the Zookeeper and its name become hbase:meta

Currently the Meta data resides on a single server, but there is an [Open Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11574) to replicate the hbase:meta's regions.

However, HBase makes a few things to overcome this shortage:

1. It gives a higher priority to make the META get online when a failure occurs
2. The information about hbase:meta is cached by the client for future interactions and is refreshed only if the regions it’s expecting to interact with based on that information don’t exist on the node it thinks they should be on. (from [HBase In Action](http://dl.e-book-free.com/2013/07/hbase_in_action.pdf) : 3.3.2 How do I find my region?), so if the Meta region went offline only requests to .META. fail.

Comment: For META table high availability do following as given [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11574):  On the server side, set hbase.meta.replica.count to the number of replicas of meta that you want to have in the cluster (defaults to 1). hbase.regionserver. meta.storefile.refresh.period should be set to a non-zero number in milliseconds - something like 30000 (defaults to 0). 
On the client/user side, set hbase.meta.replicas.use to true.

Answer (score 1):

zookeeper store the location of the RegionServer that is hosting -ROOT- 
than -ROOT- is scanned, to find the location of .META.
and by scanning .META. you find where your data is hosted

.META. and -ROOT- are tables/regions as the your tables/regions.
so if the machine hosting .META. or -ROOT- goes down 
they will be reassigned to another machine and during that time
a new client connecting trying to scan -ROOT- or .META. will get an error
no data is lost, it will just be not available until the reassignment